# Is there a way to save a draft?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there a way to save a draft post, either question or answer?

Suppose I am making a post, but it may take a few days to gather the information. Is there a way to save the draft and update based on saved data at a later time?

Comment: So regular draft does not work? You may clarify why...

Comment: Regular draft is based on cookies, is that right? It only works on save PC/browser, if I switch to another PC, it is not there. I'd like a user based draft.

Comment: You might want to look into one of the many, many online editors out there. There's even at least [one site where you can use Stack Overflow's flavor of Markdown](https://stackedit.io/editor).

Comment: Post minimal draft, immediately delete draft, continue editing deleted draft, undelete when done?